# Кнопки просвечиваются сквозь фрагменты при смене устройства

Tags: android, android-fragment, view, android-xml, fragment-transaction

Я установил targetApi = 15; На моём устройсве на 4.4.4(19 api), проблем не возникает совсем, однако,на устройстве 5.1 при открытии фрагмента по кнопке, через фон просвечивается элементы активити(кнопки, включая ImageButton), и нижний фрагмент (в проекте есть фрагмент внутри которого фрагмент).
В коде активности в которой это тоже проявляется. фрагмент создаётся:

```
  fChooser=new FileChooserFragment();
  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  ft.add(R.id.FileChooseLay,fChooser,"fChooserInMenu");
  ft.commit();
```

Код XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/FileChooseLay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Этот кусок находится в самом низу кода XML.
По нажатию кнопки происходит:

```
public void onChooseCfg(View view) {
        fChooser.ShowEl();
    }
```

В фрагменте это:

```
public void HideEl(){getView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); RefreshFile();}
public void ShowEl(){getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); RefreshFile();}
```

В `onCreateView()` фрагмента происходит вызов `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
Код фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffecb3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hideBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="HideMe" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvFile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hideBtn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bkDir"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/hideBtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hideBtn"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="UpDir" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

На моём Api 19 устройстве все работает, однако на другом они накладываются друг на друга.  Как лечить?(Костылить прятание кнопок сквозь вид? Или перекладывать кнопки из активности в новый фрагмент, который и прятать через `HideEl();`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение тривиальное: класть разметку во `FrameLayout`, а в неё `RelativeLayout` основной и фрагмента.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вместо add использовать replace при открытии нового фрагмента

Comment: При установке видимости View Фрагмента(Видим), кнопки в активности простопросвечиваются сквозь фон и элементы, как-будто они наверху разметки (Но оно блин внизу), на 4.4.4 все работает корректно, ниче не просвечивается, а на чертовом 5.1 они насквозь видны.
Что мне реплейсить если сквозь фрагмент просвечивается кнопки в активности?

Comment: Ага, а backgroud установлен у фрагмента?

Comment: Да, точно установлен, на моём 4.4.4 все нормально, и фон стоит и ниче не просвечивается

Comment: android:background="#ffecb3"
Да и код фрагмента я выложил